# Is it bad practice to use StaticMetamodel (JPA) inside ServiceImpl?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am rewriting a huge part of an existing application. We have `Group` an `SuperGroup`.

Actualy, the groupe can only store one stringValue.
To respect the new scope of the project we want the `Group` to store multiple value like date, number and boolean. The type of the `Group` depend on a value that is store inside the `SuperGroup`. (It also store the format of the group value, but this is not important)

One of the purpose of the application is to search by group value. And here is my problem.

In a service I need to implement the search that will call a DAO and determine on witch value I have to made the search.

My question is in the title. Is it bad practice to use StaticMetamodel (JPA) inside ServiceImpl?

To illustrate my question, here is the service method.

```
public Groupe getGroupeBySuperGroupeAndEntrepriseAndValue(SuperGroupe superGroupe, Entreprise entreprise, String value) {
    if (entreprise == null || StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
        return null;
    }

    GroupeDataTypeEnum groupeDataTypeEnum = GroupeDataTypeEnum.getGroupeDataTypeByTypeValue(superGroupe.getDataType());

    Object finalValue;
    SingularAttribute singularAttribute;
    switch (groupeDataTypeEnum) {
        case STRING_DATA_TYPE:
            finalValue = value;
            singularAttribute = Groupe_.stringValue;
            break;
        case NUMBER_DATA_TYPE:
            finalValue = FormatUtils.formatStringToDouble(superGroupe.getDataFormat(), value);
            singularAttribute = Groupe_.numberValue;
            break;
        case DATE_DATA_TYPE:
            finalValue = FormatUtils.formatStringToDate(superGroupe.getDataFormat(), value);
            singularAttribute = Groupe_.dateValue;
            break;
        case BOOLEAN_DATA_TYPE:
            finalValue = FormatUtils.formatStringToBoolean(superGroupe.getDataFormat(), value);
            singularAttribute = Groupe_.booleanValue;
            break;
        default :
            finalValue = null;
            break;
    }

    return groupeDAO.getGroupeBySuperGroupeAndEntrepriseAndValue(superGroupe, entreprise, finalValue, singularAttribute);
}
```

And in the DAO the search is made on the singular attribut passed in parameter.

My problem is purely conceptual. Is it OK to use SingularAttribute that is generated by  `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`  inside the service. If we left Hibernate I could  lost that StaticMetamodel, so we will have bugs. But we can regenerate them because StaticMetamodel is Java stanndard.

Is there a better way to do what I want here?

I need some help to clear my mind. Thank you by advance, any return is welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use the GroupeDataTypeEnum as type information?

Comment: It represent the type information by an int value, and then I determine the SingularAttribute and the value to use. Maybe I can store Store the SingularAttribute inside it, but it will not solve my problematic and I need the switch statement to determine de the value to get from my Group

Comment: sure but you wouldn't depend on JPA

Comment: I don't understand. SingularAttribute doesn't depend on JPA. It's generated by JPA. What do you suggest exactly? Do you mean that I should continue to use SingularAttribute, but I have to store it inside GroupeDataTypeEnum? SingularAttribute let me determine on witch column the request need to be done, so, how can I remove it?

Comment: To the core question "Is it bad practice to use StaticMetamodel (JPA) inside ServiceImpl?" - No way! Which place could be better suited? ;)

Comment: In all the application I worked on the StaticMetamodel where only used in the DAO. So I would say in the DAO. Here I have some logic so I wouldn't put it inside the DAO but in the service. That's why I posted this question. Anyway I think there is no better places to do it.